# Ember or Backbone for app with lots of similar views and data?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, data-binding, ember.js, frameworks

I am not asking "what are differences between Ember and Backbone." It's been asked before, and doesn't answer my question.

I don't need to consider syntax, or origin stories, or my developers' coding backgrounds, community size, or which is more lightweight, or readability.

But strictly based on features and performance, which framework is better suited for an app with the following characteristics:

1. Tons of very similar views with nested subviews.
2. Lots of complex data to display and sort and update.

Comment: I realize there are other JS frameworks out there. For business reasons, these are my options.

Answer (score 3):

Backbone by itself is just a library to create your own framework, whereas Ember is a full-fledged framework for building apps. If you were to go with Backbone I would suggest something like [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/). That being said, if you're looking for a framework where almost everything is already done for you and you just want to crank out screens, Ember makes this task fairly trivial. The complexity with Ember happens when you want to do something the non-ember way, in which case Backbone can allow for more flexibility.

From what you said it sounds like you are tasked with something that is large, but most of the work is fairly repeatable. I would probably go with Ember if that is the case.